# Python: os.environ.get not working for Sendgrid email

Tags: python, email, sendgrid

I'm attempting to use Sendgrid to send email. But using  os.environ.get to send email gives me a 401 error.

I set the environment variable by doing this:

```
echo 'export SENDGRID_API_KEY=Actual API key' >> ~/.zshenv
source ~/.zshenv
```

Then the code in my Python file which throws an error:

```
    message = Mail(
    from_email=#email verified by Sendgrid#,
    to_emails=user.email,
    subject='Change Password Link',
    html_content='Change your password ' + '<a href=\'' + url_for('reset_token',token=token,_external=True) + '\'>here</a>')
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
        response = sg.send(message)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending email!")
```

However, if I replace os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY') with my actual API key, it works.

Additionally, if I print(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')) right before sg = SendGridAPIClient, it prints the key correctly.

So it seems my code is able to get the key from the environment, but not use it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should work. Sendgrid won't even know the difference between hard-coding and reading an environment variable. Try debug-printing the key and check for trailing spaces or such.

Comment: Is there something special about debug-printing instead of just using print()? I did try print and it seems to be fine, although I'm wondering if you're right about trailing space or maybe even the trailing newline character? Will try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: No, nothing special; I just meant adding `print(...)`s for debugging purposes.

Comment: When you created your API key, what permissions did you give it? It could be possible that when you created the API key, you may have not given it certain access.

Other than that, what Robert suggested sounds correct to me. Check for trailing spaces.